# Is it possible to upload files to multiple google drive accounts synchronously using Drive API in Android?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Details:- I want to synchronously upload three files to three different google drive accounts from my Android Application.My current implementation is uploading all the three files in just one (last logged-in) account.So i want to know whether is it technically possible to do so?

1> Right now,I have three different classes for three Drive accounts.I am using Drive API and GooglePlay services gms:play-services:11.4.2 .
Code snippet for initializing mGoogleApiClient:-

```
 public void init(Activity context, final ICDCallback<String> cb) {
    if (this.mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        this.mGoogleApiClient = new Builder(context).addOnConnectionFailedListener(new OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                cb.failure(connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
            }
        }).addConnectionCallbacks(new ConnectionCallbacks() {
            public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                cb.success("");
            }

            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                cb.progress(0);
            }
        }).addApi(Drive.API).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"), new Scope[0]).requestEmail().build()).build();
    }
    if (this.mGoogleApiClient != null && this.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
    {
        cb.success("");
    } else {
        connect();
    }
}
```

2> Result:- This method is called each time the user is logged in and file uploading. But the mGoogleApiClient has always last logged-in google drive Account because of which I think,files are uploaded in the last logged-in account instead of three different accounts.

3>So please what should i do in this case?
i) Is it possible to save the user account info in respective class in current implementation and use it while uploading? Or is there any other better way to do that?
ii) Can Google OAuth2.0 library help if i try to save any user specific account information in corresponding drive classes?

Please suggest pointers to go ahead.

Comment: Does it have to be synchronized upload? That seems a very strange requirement since only one Drive / Google account is "active" at a time.

Comment: @tehhowch: Yes,it needs to be synchronized for now. The requirement is too strange :( . If i try to save the Google Auth class object /any related class object, can it help?

Comment: Please define (in your question) exactly what you mean when saying "at the same time". Provide (pseudo)code examples of what meets your specification, and compilable code examples of what does not.

Comment: @tehhowch: Thanks,i will soon update my question with code examples.

Comment: Have you used the official Google Drive app? Does it support what you're trying to do? If it doesn't, then what you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: @noogui : its not possible in the App. But i want to know whether file uploading can be done synchronously in this case?

Comment: dont think so. official drive app uploads 1 file at a time per account.

Comment: @noogui: Yes, right. Just one account is active at a time in App.

Comment: there's your answer right there.